# Optimal way send short string through TCP IP client from HTML application

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json

I am doing a project and I have to send different strings (START,PAUSE,STOP) through TCP IP sockets in order to inform a server.

What I want to do is send the string (START,STOP,PAUSE) by pushing a button on a HTML application.
*** I will fs.writeFile an empty string after pushing the button on the JSON file. I only want one string in my JSON file.

I tried sending some custom string direcly from the client ( clientSend.write('TEST'); ) and the server can receive them well

I tried sending different variable through php and then the JSON file but I can't seem to reach the JSON file, even when my server is running. I am wondering what would be the best way to send a single string word from html page to the client which will send the string

I tried to send to a php file to then send back to a JSON file but never got it to work.

**Node JS Client:**

```
const IP = '127.0.0.1';
const SENDPORT = 3456;

setInterval(function() { 
    var clientSend = new net.Socket();
    clientSend.connect(SENDPORT, IP, function() {
        console.log('Connected');
        fs.readFile('/string.json', (err, data) => { //might be wrong
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(data);
        });
        clientSend.write(data);
        clientSend.destroy();
    });

    clientSend.on('close', function() {
        console.log('Connection closed');
        clientSend.destroy();
    });

}, 10000);
```

**HTML Page:**

```
(...)

Start button:<button id="buttonStart"; style="background:green; 
cursor:pointer;width:300px;height:100px;">Start</button>

<br><br><br>>

Pause button:<button id="buttonStart"; style="background:orange; 
cursor:pointer;width:300px;height:100px;">Pause</button>

<br><br><br>>


Stop button:<button id="buttonStart"; style="background:red; 
cursor:pointer;width:300px;height:100px;">Stop</button>

<script 
src=https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js> 
</script>
<script>
    var start = 'start';
    //This is where I have no clue what to do
    $('#buttonStart').click(function() {
        $.post("json.php", {JSON.stringify(start)}
    );}
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$json = $_POST['start'];

/* sanity check */
if (json_decode($start) != null) {
    $file = fopen('/string.json','w+');
    fwrite($file, $start);
    fclose($file);
}
else {
 //
}
?>
```

Right now What I am really looking to get is the data inside the JSON file. It could be a .txt file too or any other thing I can fs.readfile afterward.

I cannot use any NodeJS function on the HTML page.

Performance is important too. If there is a better option to post and read small string, please tell me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I had written was good but it was not complete. I simply was not running the php code on a php server so the html page was reading a simple text.

I downloaded Wampserver and made the php run on this server than ran everything together and it works perfecly.